# Read AWS Region and AccountId from Swagger

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-cloudformation

How to get the `AWS::Region` and `AWS::AccountId` from a swagger file's `x-amazon-apigateway-integration`?

I tried many combinations following [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/aws-api-gateway-stage-variables-reference.html), but no luck - always getting "`Invalid ARN`" when building the Cloudformation stack.

I was expecting to be able to do something like this in the swagger file:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  uri:
    Fn::Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${stageVariables.myFunctionName}/invocations
```

However if I hardcode the Region and Account ids, it works:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  uri: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:${stageVariables.myFunctionName}/invocations
```

Comment: What does your full CloudFormation look like? Are you embedding Swagger within the CloudFormation using "Body", or are you referencing a swagger file using "BodyS3Location"? This is key to answering your question. If its the latter, it simply won't work. We generate variations of our Swagger to get around this. If its the former, it may work with some changes. Its unfortunately StageVariables don't allow substituting the full lambda arn

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this that works.

```
  ApiGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Body:
        openapi: 3.0.1
        paths:
          '/myGetEndpoint':
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:myLambdaFunction/invocations'
```